# Minecraft EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) [ig8icd64.dll+0x16b87]

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

When I launch Minecraft (modded or unmodded) I get this error:

```
EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005)  
Problematic frame as [ig8icd64.dll+0x16b87]
```

I have tried every solution on the internet and it is still not working, some people suggest getting new graphic card, but my computer is like 6 months old and I have the latest soft drivers installed. I have got Intel Iris Graphics 6100 with an i3 core processor (I have not found out a code name yet).

I used to have this error and it just randomly fixed itself like 3 months ago. For any other info just ask me.